# Visual Studio 2010 becomes very slow when editing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, intellisense, visual-assist

My `VS2010` solution is a large scale one, with 100+ source/header files, and several external library being included. I use `VAssistX` plugin. Yesterday I added a new .cc file and it started getting slow when editing. Very lag when typing.

I tried to rebuild `VS2010` intellisense database (Project > Rescan Solution), and rebuild `VAssistX` symbol database. Is there any other thing I can try in order to fix this issue? Or any way I can find out what's the root cause.

PS: I am guessing this lag is due to symbol parsing. Whenever I type in that new file, `VS2010`/`VAssistX` is looking up or updating the symbol database. Somehow this operation is cause lagging.

Comment: Visual Assist turns off the VS intellisense parser so you'll need to focus on VA for this problem.  This is a memory-hungry kind of add-in so make sure your machine has enough oompf to support it.  Never try using it if you have only 2 gigabyte of RAM for example.  Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: I got 8GB ram and usually keep 1-2GB free memory available. I am worried about the include file in the new .cc file may cause a loop, which causing VA repeatedly parsing some files again and again. Is it possible and how to find out this issue? I am trying to use "Process Monitor" to track if any unusual file accessing by VS2010.

Comment: I noticed that the CPU (the core) is always at 100% when editing.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but for those that still work with it, Visual Studio 2010 doesn't cope well with a lot of files being open. This might be the problem here. Try right clicking your current file and selecting Close All But This and see if that works for you.